# Python while statement setting difficulty for hangman game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working through Al Sweigart's Invent Your Own Computer Games and am on chapter 10 (The Hangman Game).  I am unable to set the difficulty using a while loop.  Currently it doesn't even print the statement under my while loop.  If I change it to while difficulty != '': I can get it to print the statement and accept my input, but it still doesn't change the difficulty.  Here is the code:

```
difficulty = ''
while difficulty not in 'EMH':
    print("Enter difficulty: E - easy, M - medium, H - hard.")
    difficulty = input().upper()
if difficulty == 'M':
    del HANGMAN_ART[8]
    del HANGMAN_ART[7]
if difficulty == 'H':
    del HANGMAN_ART[8]
    del HANGMAN_ART[7]
    del HANGMAN_ART[5]
    del HANGMAN_ART[3]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You probably want `input().upper()`

Comment: it's not properly indented to begin with

Comment: ```'' in anystring``` evaluates to True also.

Comment: I have fixed the .upper() mistake, unfortunately that didn't fix the program.  I followed the indentation in the book, can you explain how it should be indented? Thanks

Comment: So what the `difficulty` variable contains after the `while` loop? And what's exactly your problem, that it enters neither of the conditions, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your `while` loop that you need to fix. The first is that it is never run in the first place, because `'' not in 'EMH'` evaluates to `False` initially. The second is that you're setting `difficulty` to `input().upper` instead of `input().upper()`. Here's a sample fix:

```
difficulty = ''
while True:
    print("Enter difficulty: E - easy, M - medium, H - hard.")
    difficulty = input().upper()
    if difficulty in 'EMH':
        break
```

As Jared Goguen noted in the comments, you can also keep the same loop condition but change the initial input.

```
difficulty = 'invalid_input'
while difficulty not in 'EMH':
    ...
```

Comment: I don't think I agree with changing the condition of the loop and using `break`. It might be better to keep the original condition and update the initialization of `difficulty` to be `difficulty = 'invalid_input'`.

Comment: @JaredGoguen That's another perfectly reasonable solution.